# Looking for an idiom for boring but critical part of work

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

I sincerely hope this is relevant:

I am looking for an idiom for a boring but essential part of work, that goes hand in hand with the core interesting parts of it. On the lines of "peas and carrots" but where one looks more important and interesting, yet the other is essential, e.g. (due to lack of imagination on my part) more like "Matar Paneer" (Peas and Cottage cheese, an Indian cottage cheese curry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a BrE speaker I might use the following phrases (although they have slightly different connotations, and other meanings):

> Bread and Butter - The day to day repetitive tasks that are easy to do.
>
> Grunt Work - The slog, or non-thinking part, that just needs to get done.
>
> Gravy - The easy work that gets the money.

Comment: Gravy is what was making sense to me too! not sure why I am leaning to food-related stuff though :D, the context is/was fairly technical.

Comment: '*<x> and <y> are the hardest part, the rest is all gravy*' is an example of how I might use the *gravy* option in a phrase.